# Find the probability they are siblings?

Tags: probability

Given there are $5$ pairs of siblings, answer the question:

What is the probability that $2$ randomly chosen people are siblings?

My answer: $\frac{10}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{9}$

What is the probability that $4$ randomly chosen people are not related? i.e. no siblings among the $4$ chosen.

My answer: $\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{7}$?

Kindly advise thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My bad. it shd be times.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is right, but the second is not. If you apply the same reasoning to the second problem that you used in the first, you can argue that the probability is

$$\frac{10}{10}\cdot\frac89\cdot\frac68\cdot\frac47=\frac8{21}\;.$$

There is no restriction on the first pick. Once you’ve picked one person, $9$ remain, and $8$ of them are not siblings of the first one picked. One you’ve picked two who aren’t siblings, $8$ remain, and $6$ of those $8$ are not siblings of either of the two that you’ve already chosen. Finally, once you’ve picked three, no two of whom are siblings, $7$ remain, $4$ of whom are not sibling to any of the three already chosen.

Alternatively, you can count subsets. In the second problem, for instance, there are $\binom{10}4$ possible sets of $4$ people. Now consider a set that contains no pair of siblings: it must contain one member of each of $4$ sibling pairs. There are $\binom54$ ways to choose which $4$ sibling pairs will be represented in the set, and for each of those $4$ pairs there are $2$ ways to pick a member of the pair, so there are altogether $\binom54\cdot2^4$ sets with no sibling pair. Thus, the desired probability is

$$\frac{\binom54\cdot2^4}{\binom{10}4}=\frac{80}{210}=\frac8{21}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

First part is ok.

For the second part, there is no restriction on the first choice.
And once you have chosen, you can only choose from $8$ non-siblings, then from $6$ non-siblings and so on,
thus $Pr = \dfrac{10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}$